# ASP.NET MVC Authorise attribute not working, followed guidance from other questions but still get straight in

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, authorization

I've got an ASP.NET MVC application that I want to secure. I've added the `[Authorize]` attribute to the controllers, I've also added

filters.Add(new System.Web.Mvc.AuthorizeAttribute());

to the `RegisterGlobalFilters` method and finally, confirmed

FilterConfig.RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);

is in the `global.asax.cs`, `Application_start` method.

I can still hit my controller and return the views fine without logging in, actually never have logged in, so sure nothing is cached anywhere.

Any ideas pointers to what I'm missing here?

Thanks in advance

J

Answer (score 0):

Are your users coming from Azure AD?

You have to set an access policy in Startup.cs

```
services.AddAuthorization(options =>
        {
            options.FallbackPolicy = options.DefaultPolicy;
            options.AddPolicy("<enter policy name>", policy =>
                                policy.RequireRole("<role from AD"));
```

You can add multiple roles to a single policy like ("Role 1","Role 2","etc")

And then in your controller you have to specify which policy should have access

```
[Authorize(Policy = "<policy name from Startup.cs")]
```

Comment: No, they're not.  It should just be the standard out of the box OWIN, which I believe should just work, but sadly it's not.  Pretty much about to give up on it now and roll my own.  Shame though, hours of work I really shouldn't need to do :-(